# Multicast listening and interface IP address change

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, multicast

I am binding to a multicast group and port to listen a multicast stream.  Since adding the group membership (via IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP) requires specifying a specific network interface, what will happen when that interface IP address changes?

Do I have start again with a new socket and add membership? This is related to Linux/C environment. I do see some packets comming in without changing IP, but I feel I have to restart.

thanks,
gl

Comment: Under Linux you have to bind to the multicast group to receive packets sent to that group. When you say "bind to local IP", do you mean the interface IP you provide with the call to IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP?

Comment: yes.     /                                                                              
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(MCAST_GROUP)
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(localIP) /
The question is what if localIP changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel appears to be tracking the interface based on the interface identifier rather than the interface IP address.  From a couple of experiments, it looks like your application won't need to have any special handling

**Experiment 1: Host Receiving**

Here's an experiment I put together with Ubuntu to test if the host will continue to receive across the interface IP change.

```
$ uname -a
$ Linux joel-VirtualBox 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a simple Python test script for running a multicast receiver on a network interface eth2, identified by static IP 192.168.33.11:

```
import socket
import struct

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP )
sock.bind( ('',50400) )

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton('239.254.2.4') + socket.inet_aton('192.168.33.11') )

while True:
    print sock.recv( 2048 )

sock.close( sock )
```

Once running the python script, I can verify the membership by running:

```
$ netstat -gn
lo              1      224.0.0.1
eth0            1      224.0.0.251
eth0            1      224.0.0.1
eth1            1      224.0.0.1
eth2            1      224.0.0.251
eth2            1      239.254.2.4
eth2            1      224.0.0.1
```

From another PC, I ran a multicast sender, sending to 239.254.2.4:50400 and verified the data is printed.  I then changed the static IP to 192.168.33.12 and verified the membership is still reported by netstat and my python script can continue to receive data.

**Experiment 2: IGMP Membership Reports**

I put another experiment together to see what happens to the IGMP membership reports:

[image: Capture IGMP reports]

As you can see when the change of IP address happens, no new IGMP report for 239.254.2.4 is generated.  But when the script is killed, an IGMP Leave message is sent.

This could be considered "a hole" though any switch or router that is performing IGMP snooping or multicast routing will be periodically issuing IGMP queries.  Our host will respond to this query by sending its current memberships (including the membership for 239.254.2.4).

Comment: Thanks. I did try similar experiments and I saw the similar results. But I was not sure. One question I have is, while trying to subscribe for mcast data, I am giving my local interface IP which is the one getting changed.

Comment: That's the same thing I did in my experiments.  My local interface IP is 192.168.33.11 (changed to 192.168.33.12).  This is specified in the call to IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP as the last parameter (in my example python code)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to rejoin the group. Both the localhost and the router only have a count of members, and in both cases if it's non-zero it will deliver the multicast internally. But I could be wrong.